# What does :: and ~ do in css?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-selectors

I was looking at a code made by a guy in twitter and it is like this :

```
div::after {
-webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
}

div ~ div {
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

what is it ?

Comment: Here you go: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/ `::` is a pseudo-element, while `div ~ div` is a div that comes after a div.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-css-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-selector-do and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704049/what-does-the-double-colon-mean-in-css

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The tilde character (~) is the siblings selector

```
h2 ~ p { color:red; }
```

for example would make the paragraphs red in the below code

```
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>The selector above matches this paragraph.</p>
<p>The selector above matches this paragraph.</p>
```

the :: is used for `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements which together with the `content:` allow you to put, for example, an icon before every link

```
a::before { content:url(link.png); }
```

Comment: `~` doesn't exactly match siblings - only siblings preceded by an element of the first type. A `<p>` before the `<h2>` in your example wont match.

Answer (score 24):

> The double colon replaced the single-colon selectors for
>   pseudo-elements in CSS3 to make an explicit distinction between
>   pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. For backward compatibility, the
>   single-colon syntax is acceptable for pre-CSS3 selectors. So, :after
>   is a pseudo-class and ::after is a pseudo-element.

---

> The general sibling selector is available in CSS3, and the combinator
>   used in this selector is a tilde character (~).
>
> The selector matches elements that are siblings of a given element.
>   This example will match a p element if it’s a sibling of an h2
>   element:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector

http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/05/after-v-after-what-is-double-colon-notation/

Comment: Evotech has got it wrong. `:after` with a single colon is not a pseudo class, it always has been a pseudo-element, even though you can use the pseudo-class syntax.

Comment: Yes ::after and :after are the same thing, both pseudo-elements, as the spec says here http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements

Answer (score 9):

The `::` is used for [pseudo elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements) in CSS3.

The `~` is the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) in CSS3, it is used to select elements that follow another element at the same level.