# What does the "~" (tilde/squiggle/twiddle) CSS selector mean?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Searching for the `~` character isn't easy. I was looking over some CSS and found this

```
.check:checked ~ .content {
}
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1661, accepted):

The `~` selector is in fact the [subsequent-sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators) (previously called general sibling combinator [until 2017](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1382)):

> The subsequent-sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~)
> character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
> elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
> document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
> precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
> second one.

Consider the following example:

```css
.a ~ .b {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="b">b</li>
  <li class="a">a</li>
  <li class="x">x</li>
  <li class="b">b</li>
  <li class="b">b</li>
</ol>
```

`.a ~ .b` matches the 4th and 5th list item because they:

- Are `.b` elements
- Are siblings of `.a`
- Appear after `.a` in HTML source order.

Likewise, `.check:checked ~ .content` matches all `.content` elements that are siblings of `.check:checked` and appear after it.

Comment: @SalmanA, Surely there got to be a way to select everything before instead of everything after? ¶ https://stackoverflow.com/q/28007288/632951

Comment: @Pacerier no. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/87015, the reasons applies to your question as well. TL;DR CSS is designed so that browser does not have to go back (or up) and re-style some element if current element matches a rule. Imagine changing font size of entire `<body>` after it is rendered only because the last is `<div class=reset-font>`. @HerrSerker is correct but (IMO) the sentence is incorrectly phrased.

Comment: `@card-prefix-cls: ~"@{css-prefix}card";`, I have seen the tilde symbol of ~ in less style file, what does it mean?

Answer (score 322):

Good to also check the other [combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators) in the family and to get back to what is this specific one.

- `ul li`
- `ul > li`
- `ul + ul`
- `ul ~ ul`

Example checklist:

- `ul li` - ***Looking inside*** - Selects **all** the `li` elements placed (anywhere) inside the `ul`; [**Descendant combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)
- `ul > li` - ***Looking inside*** - Selects **only the direct** `li` elements of `ul`; i.e. it will only select direct children `li` of `ul`; [**Child combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)
- `ul + ul` - ***Looking outside*** - Selects the `ul` **immediately following** the `ul`; It is not looking inside, but looking outside for the immediately following element; [**Adjacent sibling combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) / [**Next-sibling combinator**](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)
- `ul ~ ul` - ***Looking outside*** - Selects **all the following** `ul`'s, but both `ul`'s should be having the same parent; [**General sibling combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) /  [**Subsequent-sibling combinator**](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators)

---

The one we are looking at here is the [**General sibling combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) /  [**Subsequent-sibling combinator**](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators)

Comment: _Looking outside_ can be misleading. ... _Looking alongside_ may be better.

Answer (score 181):

**General sibling combinator**

> The general sibling combinator selector is very similar to the adjacent sibling combinator selector. The difference is that the element being selected doesn't need to immediately succeed the first element, but can appear anywhere after it.

[More info](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some more elaborate snippets based on the first answer.

Basically `~` will select

- multiple adjacent siblings
- multiple sibling groups within the same tag
- multiple times all over the document

```css
.a ~ .b {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">1st</li>
  <li class="b">2nd</li>
  <li class="c">3rd</li>
  <li class="a">4th</li>
  <li class="b">5th</li>
  <li class="b">6th</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="a">1st</li>
  <li class="b">2nd</li>
  <li class="c">3rd</li>
  <li class="a">4th</li>
  <li class="b">5th</li>
  <li class="b">6th</li>
</ul>
```

`+` will select

- exactly one adjacent sibling
- multiple sibling groups within the same tag
- multiple times all over the document

```css
.a + .b {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">1st</li>
  <li class="b">2nd</li>
  <li class="c">3rd</li>
  <li class="a">4th</li>
  <li class="b">5th</li>
  <li class="b">6th</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="a">1st</li>
  <li class="b">2nd</li>
  <li class="c">3rd</li>
  <li class="a">4th</li>
  <li class="b">5th</li>
  <li class="b">6th</li>
</ul>
```

Or stated another way...

- `+` is one adjacent sibling
- `~` is all adjacent siblings