# Delete specific range of elements JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Html:

```
<select id ="combooptions">
          <option id="combostart" value=""></option>
 </select>
```

js:

```
var str = "";
if (combonews.length > 0)
        for (var i in combonews) {
            str += "<option value='" + combonews[i][0] + "'>" + combonews[i][1] + "</option>";
        }
    jQuery("#combooptions").append(str);
```

It works fine, but now I want to remove those appended one, leaving the initial 1 option tag, as shown above.
I tried:

```
jQuery("#combooptions").html('');
 //or
jQuery("#combooptions").append('');
//or
jQuery("#combostart").append('');
//or
jQuery("#combostart").html('');
```

but no success.

Please help 
thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you gave the first `option` a unique ID, just do:

```
$('#combostart ~ option').remove();
```

[What does the "~" (tilde/squiggle/twiddle) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10782054/901048)

Comment: Thank you guys,all those were working, but since you were the first I chose yours @Blazemonger as an answer. Appreciate

Answer (score 3):

To shrink a select list, you can also lower the number of options:

```
document.getElementById("combooptions").length = 1;
```

With jQuery:

```
$("#combooptions")[0].length = 1;
```

More generic idea to remove "all but the first":

```
$("#combooptions :not(:first-child)").remove();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kVRpy/

Answer (score 1):

You could select all options and then remove the one with id combostart from your selection.
Then call [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove the unwanted options.

```
$('#combooptions option').not('#combostart').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#combooptions').html("<option id='combostart' value=''></option>");
```