# target div with a checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a checkbox which hides/shows a div. It works when I put the checkbox directly above the div. When I place the checkbox somewhere else in the page (for better usability) it doesnt't work. Is there a way to target a certain div to make the checkbox work from everywhere on the page?

Here is the HTML-code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-result" checked="checked">  </input>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: There could be additional code that's breaking the functionality of the page. You might have to post a bit more (what's on the page) code. I've had this exact problem before.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-css-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-selector-do. Moving the div to other locations is breaking your selector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using CSS, you can select child elements and adjacent elements, so what you are trying to do will work if `div` is placed right after the checkbox but if you want to make it work when `div` is somewhere else(above the checkbox), you need to use JavaScript, if it's after, you can use `+` to select adjacent element or nested adjacent element

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9MpPT/)

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<div>Toggle Using CSS</div>

input[type=checkbox]:checked + div {
    display: block;
}

div {
    display: none;
}
```

Targetting `div` which is farther away somewhere (But not before the `checkbox`) like this

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/9MpPT/2/)

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + a + .blah .target {
    display: block;
}

.target {
    display: none;
}

<input type="checkbox" />
<a href="#">Dummy Link</a>

<div class="blah">
    <div class="target">Complicated Selector, Isn't It?</div>
</div>
```

> Explanation : `input[type=checkbox]:checked + a + .blah .target` Over
>   here we select the checkbox which is in a checked state, and than we
>   chain this by selecting the adjacent element which is an anchor tag,
>   and than we select another adjacent element which is adjacent to `a`
>   tag which is `div` with a class `.blah`, and than we select nested child element with a class `.target`

Using jQuery To Do (Doesn't matter where the target element is) [**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/9MpPT/1/)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme" />
<a href="#">Dummy Link</a>
<div id="show_on_check" style="display:none">
    This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkme').change(function() {
        $('#show_on_check').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
   display: none;
}
```

Will select every `div` element that is preceded by a `input` that is checked.  The reason why it probably breaks is because the input is not preceding the `div` (Like you state in your question)

Comment: I believe that's not quite correct. It will select every `div` that shares a parent with a checked input.

Comment: @Chris - `E ~ F an F element preceded by an E element`

Answer (score 0):

Use the element IDs in your selectors:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-result" checked="checked"/>

<div id="myDiv">showme</div>

<style>
    #toggle-result:checked ~ #myDiv {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```