# Change an element style by hovering another

Tags: html, css

### The goal

Change an element by hovering another with CSS.

### The problem

I don't know the syntax. Any ideas?

### Code spotlight

I want to change  `.frame` by hovering `.app > a`. The CSS syntax is spotlighted below:

```
.app a:hover ->¹ .frame {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.frame {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

¹ *just illustration.*

[(Also available in jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/jWA3s/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
.app:hover ~ .frame {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.frame {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/jWA3s/1/

---

Reference: [What does the "~" (tilde/squiggle/twiddle) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-css-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-selector-do)

Comment: This solution is available for old browsers like IE 8?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Not that I know of. You will need to use javascript for older browsers.

Comment: No problem ^_^ Happy to help @GuilhermeOderdenge :-D

Comment: This works in IE7+. Also, a thing to be careful of, if .frame isn't a sibling after the link this won't work, but you can worry about that later. =)

Comment: Another good reference: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/