# How to use :not selector with :nth-of-type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Im about styling a table. I want each odd row to have a specific background except the first row which contains headers.

I have used the following code which does not work:

```
.new-items-table tr:nth-of-type(odd):not(.new-items-table tr):nth-of-type(1)
{
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you wrap your headers in the <thead> tag and the body of a table in the <tbody> tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some options:

**1.** [`~` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-css-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-selector-do) - http://jsfiddle.net/5sKqX/

```
.new-items-table tr ~ tr:nth-of-type(odd) {background-color:red;}
```

It matched `tr`s that are after other `tr`s, so it skips the header row.

**2.** use `<thead>` - http://jsfiddle.net/5sKqX/1/

```
<thead>
    <tr><th>Header</th></tr>        
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Css:

```
.new-items-table tr:nth-of-type(even) {background-color:red;}
```

**3.** use `:not(:first-child)` - http://jsfiddle.net/5sKqX/2/

```
.new-items-table tr:nth-of-type(odd):not(:first-child) {background-color:red;}
```

Comment: I tested it. It looker great. ~ worker nice, I always thought about such string...great..thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can just do:

```
.new-items-table tr:nth-child(2n + 3) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

`2n + 1` is the same thing as `odd`. `2n + 3` skips the first two rows.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YVTTA/**

Comment: thanks very much. But is there any possible change to use it next to (odd) keyword?

Comment: @Mostafa: If you wrap the header in a `<thead>` and the body in a `<tbody>`, you can just do `.new-items-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd)`

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in the comment to your question, wrap your headers in `<thead></thead>` and the body of a table in `<tbody></tbody>`. Then you could simply use the following rule:

```
.new-items-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: red;
}
```