# Select all elements before element with class?

Tags: html, css

In CSS is it possible to select all elements before an element with a given class?

Example HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href>One</a>
    <a href>Two</a>
    <a href>Three</a>
    <a href class="active">Four</a>
    <a href>Five</a>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.active:(all-before) {
    border-left: solid 1px #C0FFEE;
}
```

So links 'One', 'Two', and 'Three' would would have a left border but 'Four' and 'Five' would not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

a.active, a.active ~ * {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href>One</a>
    <a href>Two</a>
    <a href>Three</a>
    <a href class="active">Four</a>
    <a href>Five</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay. What is really going to work is the use of `flex-direction` in combination with the `~` selector.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* could also be column-reverse*/
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.item {
  /* just styling */
  margin: 0 8px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

/* we are still selecting every element after according to HTML
 * but as they have reversed order, we're applying styles to all
 * elements that were rendered before */
.item:hover ~ .item {
  color: coral;
  border-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- notice how children are ordered in reverse direction -->
  <div class="item">Third</div>
  <div class="item">Second</div>
  <div class="item">First</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

A much easy solution, first select the `</a>` element with class `.active` and the `</a>` elements after it using using `.active ~ a, .active`, then just put it inside the `:not()` pseudo-class on `</a>` tag, `a:not(.active ~ a, .active)` this will select all `</a>` elements except the ones with the class `.active` and the `</a>` elements the come after it.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:not(.active ~ a, .active) {
  border-left: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href>One</a>
  <a href>Two</a>
  <a href>Three</a>
  <a href class="active">Four</a>
  <a href>Five</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Baraa Al-Tabbaa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28007477/4045640) has a drawback that all other elements' value will be set to none.

To avoid this, you can use multiple `:not` selectors, so the rest of the elements can still inherent properties from the parent.

```css
a:not(a.active ~ a):not(a.active) {
  border-left: solid 5px #C0FFEE;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href>One</a>
    <a href>Two</a>
    <a href>Three</a>
    <a href class="active">Four</a>
    <a href>Five</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, Normally it's not possible, but you can hack it someway.

So for example if you want to do this:

```
.active:(all-before) {
    border-left: solid 1px #C0FFEE;
}
```

then you can do this:

```
a {
    border-left: solid 1px #C0FFEE;
}
a.active, a.active~a {
    border-left: none;
}
```

So you put the style you want in the first selector, and then you disable that design in the second selector.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/prrd14u2/

Also you can use javascript, jquery as another solution.