# How can I get all elements before a particular element using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML file which looks like below:

```
<div class="img-row">

    <div class="img-column move">
        <img class="demo" src="/image/001.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="img-column move">
        <img class="demo" src="/image/002.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="img-column move moving">
        <img class="demo" src="/image/003.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="img-column move">.
        <img class="demo" src="/image/004.jpg">
    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, I have four child divs under the parent div `.img-row` which contains the class `.move` and the third child div contains an additional class `.moving`. I want to select all the child before the child containing `.moving` class. Note any child could contain the `.moving` class and in any scenarios I want all the children before it.

So this is what I do

```
document.querySelectorAll('.move:not(.moving)')
```

But it also selects the last child in this case. How do I ensure only the children before the class `.moving` is selected using JavaScript?

I found a similar question on Stack Overflow, *[Select all elements before element with class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007288/select-all-elements-before-element-with-class)*, but the solution provided is in **CSS**. I want a **JavaScript** solution instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use convert NodeList to Array and then slice to the first index of element that has `moving` class

```js
const allElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.move'))
const expectedElements = allElements.slice(
  0,
  allElements.findIndex(element => element.classList.contains('moving'))
)

console.log(expectedElements.length)
```

```html
<div class="img-row">

  <div class="img-column move">
    <img class="demo" src="/image/001.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="img-column move">
    <img class="demo" src="/image/002.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="img-column move moving">
    <img class="demo" src="/image/003.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="img-column move">.
    <img class="demo" src="/image/004.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get it in a single selector because the `:not()` pseudo-class doesn't allow reaching beyond self `:scope`. So I'd do it with a simple recursive function to populate an array.

```js
const moving = document.querySelector('.moving')
const befores = getBefores(moving)
console.log(befores.length)

function getBefores(element, array = []) {
  const previous = element.previousElementSibling
  if(!previous)
    return array.reverse()
  array.push(previous)
  return getBefores(previous, array)
}
```

```html
<div class="img-row">

    <div class="img-column move">
        <img class="demo" src="/image/001.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="img-column move"> 
        <img class="demo" src="/image/002.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="img-column move moving">
        <img class="demo" src="/image/003.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="img-column move">
        <img class="demo" src="/image/004.jpg">
    </div>

</div>
```