# Is there a CSS / JS querySelector for "upto"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/p5bweLnc/10/

```
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a1" class="bar">
  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a2" class="bar">
  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a3" class="bar">
  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a4" class="bar">
  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a5" class="bar">
  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a6" class="bar">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

JS:

```
let fourth = document.querySelector(`#a4`);
```

Let's say I have selected the fourth one using the above JS. Is there a querySelector which lets me grab all the `bar` class divs which are BEFORE this fourth one? So a1, a2, a3? Or, is there a way to grab the previous one - a3?

Something like an "upto" selector and from a different parent?

Comment: @mandy8055 This is a very common question and have been asked many, *many* times before. Duplicate targets can easily be found: *[How to get all elements before a particular element using pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63805749)*.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any query selector like that but you can achieve it with this code

```js
let fourth = document.querySelector('#a4');
let allBars = document.querySelectorAll('.foo .bar');

// Convert NodeList to an array and find the index of the fourth element
let barArray = Array.from(allBars);
let fourthIndex = barArray.indexOf(fourth);

// Select all elements before the fourth element
let previousElements = barArray.slice(0, fourthIndex);
previousElements.forEach((previousElement) => {
    console.log(previousElement);
    
    // for example
    previousElement.style.width = 300 + 'px';
    previousElement.style.height = 300 + 'px';
    previousElement.style.backgroundColor = 'aqua';
    previousElement.style.marginTop = 10 + 'px';
    
})
```

```html
    <div class="foo">
        <div id="a1" class="bar">
        
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="foo">
        <div id="a2" class="bar">
        
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="foo">
        <div id="a3" class="bar">
        
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="foo">
        <div id="a4" class="bar">
        
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="foo">
        <div id="a5" class="bar">
        
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="foo">
        <div id="a6" class="bar">
        
        </div>
      </div>
```

Check it out here.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this way but it seems "heavy". Wondering if there's a better way? Also, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in querySelector that I am aware of which directly grabs all the elements before a specific element in the way you mentioned. Having said that, you can achieve your requirement using `js` by iterating through the elements with the `bar` class and collecting the ones that come before the selected element.

```
const allBars = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');
const previousBars = [];

for (let bar of allBars) {
  if (bar.id === 'a4') break;
              //  ^^ or any id as per requirement
  previousBars.push(bar);
}
console.log(previousBars); // contains the elements with id a1, a2, and a3
```

```js
const allBars = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');
const previousBars = [];

for (let bar of allBars) {
  if (bar.id === 'a4') break;       
  previousBars.push(bar);
}

console.log(previousBars);
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a1" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a2" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a3" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a4" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a5" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a6" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
```

---

To only grab the previous element (`a3`), you can use the *[`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling)* property:

```js
const previousBar = fourth.parentElement.previousElementSibling.querySelector('.bar');
console.log(previousBar); // returns the element with id a3
```

```js
let fourth = document.querySelector('#a4');
let previousBar = fourth.parentElement.previousElementSibling.querySelector('.bar');

console.log(previousBar);
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a1" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a2" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a3" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a4" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a5" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div id="a6" class="bar">

  </div>
</div>
```