# Show div and hide another on hover with transition

Tags: css

I have searched other questions but none are giving the result I am looking for.

I am trying to :hover in order to show another div and also hide another div at the same time. I can't wrap all divs in one parent div, because then the div I want to hide being :hover over will trigger the show/hide... and in addition do it with a nice transition.

Only when hovering over the 'hover me' text should the show/hide trigger.

The .remove_me class and text 'make me disappear' isn't disappearing on :hover. That is what I am unable to achieve.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goldengonaz/uskzvz85/)

CSS

```
.hover_me {
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    background:#ccc;
    width:70px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
.show_me {
    display:none;
}
.hover_me:hover + .remove_me {
    display:none;
}
.hover_me:hover + .show_me {
    display:block;
}
.remove_me {
    display:block;
```

HTML

```
<div class="hover_me">hover me</div>
<div class="show_me">show me</div>
<div class="remove_me">make me disappear</div>
```

This for example is **not** what I want to happen: http://jsfiddle.net/MBLZx/ the show/hide should only be triggered by the 'hover me' text

Answer (score 1):

It should work as you want it to if you do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x28ca9x6/1/):

I changed your CSS code

```
.hover_me:hover + .remove_me {
    display:none;
}
```

To:

```
//Note the tilde
.hover_me:hover ~ .remove_me {
    display:none;
}
```

[**Explanation on the tilde**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10782297/3666810)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your selector, and changed the display (that can not be animated) to opacity (that can)

```css
.hover_me {
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    background:red;
    width:70px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
.show_me {
    opacity: 0;
}
.hover_me:hover ~ .remove_me {
    opacity: 0;
}
.hover_me:hover + .show_me {
    opacity: 1;
}
.remove_me {
    margin-top: -1em;
    opacity: 1;
}

div {
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover_me">hover me</div>
<div class="show_me">show me</div>
<div class="remove_me">make me disappear</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually to select the `remove_me` you have to apply the one more `+` as `show_me` lies in between. `+` select the next tag class. so we have to put the `+ .show_me` on between

```
.hover_me:hover + .show_me + .remove_me {
    display:none;
}
```

check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/enmxx59b/

Answer (score 0):

You need to ...

1. use the general adjacent selector `~` and not the direct adjacent selector `+` to make `.remove_me` "disappear"
2. use `opacity` or any other property that you can use with transition (not `display`) to create a show/hide effect

Change your CSS as follows:

```
.hover_me:hover ~ .remove_me{
    display:none;
}
```

[**Demo fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/uskzvz85/2/)

```css
.hover_me {
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    background:red;
    width:70px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
.show_me {
    opacity: 0;
}
.hover_me:hover ~ .remove_me {
    opacity: 0;
}
.hover_me:hover ~ .show_me {
    opacity: 1;
}
.remove_me {
    opacity: 1;
}
.toggled{
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity 300ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover_me">hover me</div>
<div class="toggled show_me">show me</div>
<div class="toggled remove_me">make me disappear</div>
```