# Change grandparent CSS

Tags: css

I'm creating a dropdown menu just with CSS (I followed this tutorial - http://kmturley.blogspot.pt/2014/06/responsive-mobile-dropdown-navigation.html).

I understood that with the selector ~ we can access to parent. My question is: is it possible to access to grandparent with this selector? (Or another one?) I really dont want to use javascript (or similar).

Thanks so much.

Comment: The [tilde selects a general sibling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean). You can't select the parent using pure CSS, so there won't be any way to select a grandparent.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that too but I wasn't really sure. Thanks. :)