# My parent element is not getting affected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a sliding hamburger menu, and I am unable to move the div to the left when the checkbox (icon) is checked. The HTML for the following:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/user.jpg') }}">
        <a href="#">Sameer Manek</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="window">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
    <label for="nav-trigger"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></label>
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.nav-trigger:checked + label {
    left: 215px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .window {
    background-color: transparent;
    left: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.nav-trigger + label, .window {
    transition: left 0.2s;
}
```

The 1st and the last CSS are applied properly and the label moves to left from its current position, but the div `.window` does not

Answer (score 1):

The tilde '`~`' is not a parent selector ([see this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean)) and there isn't currently a parent selector in CSS ([see this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).)

You'll need to use some javascript to select the parent element. jQuery makes this easy if you're already using it.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS won't work for you because `~` doesn't affect parent elements in the DOM.

```
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .window { }
```

I would *not* add JavaScript to a thing unless you absolutely can't accomplish the task purely with CSS. In your case, a very small HTML change will allow you to keep things pure CSS.

You have to arrange your HTML such that your `.nav-trigger` checkbox and `.window`are at the same level in the DOM.

**HTML Changes**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></label>

<div class="window">    
  <!-- window contents here -->
</div>
```

**CSS Changes**

Using `translate` will always be smoother than using `left` to move something around the screen. Using `translate` is nice because it forces hardware acceleration. Your UI will feel more like a native app, which is always what you want.

```
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .window {
    ...
    transform: translateX(200px); /* swapped 'left' for 'transform' */
}
.nav-trigger + label, .window {
    transition: transform 0.2s; /* swapped 'left' for 'transform' */
}
```

**Demo**

http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/vGzBRm?editors=1100