# jQuery .not method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some HTML markup for a set of menu controls that is basically as follows.  As you will note, the markup in each `<div class="row">` repeats.  This repeating code is that same for each menu control set.

```
<div id="menuModal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
           <i>Control Icon</i>
           <span>Control Label</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
           <i>Control Icon</i>
           <span>Control Label</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
           <i>Control Icon</i>
           <span>Control Label</span>            
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
           <i>Control Icon</i>
           <span>Control Label</span>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
           <i>Control Icon</i>
           <span>Control Label</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
           <i>Control Icon</i>
           <span>Control Label</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
           <i>Control Icon</i>
           <span>Control Label</span>            
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
           <i>Control Icon</i>
           <span>Control Label</span>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm setting the color of each `div class="col-xs-6">` control label, EXCEPT for the first of these labels with the following jQuery selectors and method:

```
$( "#menuModal" ).find( "div.row > div.col-xs-6 > span" ).not( "div.row:eq(0) > div.col-xs-6 > span" ).css( "color", "#669900" );
```

The jQuery statement above sets the label color of EVERY `div class="col-xs-6"` label, including the first one.  I can't figure out why the `.not` method selector won't work.

Any ideas?  I'm banging my head on this...

Comment: That's actually weird. A possible explanation is that perhaps jQuery allows only *simple selectors* for `filter` and `not`.

Answer (score 1):

You may exclude the first row like this:

```
$( "#menuModal" ).find( "div.row:not(:first) > div.col-xs-6 > span" )
```

Comment: yep, I know. but I thought this one is shorter. I did exact the same change today in my own code ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use like this:

```
$( "#menuModal" ).find( "div.row:not(:first) > div.col-xs-6 > span" )
     .css( "color", "#669900" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use native CSS selectors instead:

```
$("#menuModal div.row ~ div.row > div.col-xs-6 > span")
```

This will skip first div.row even if it is not the first child.

Comment: interesting
what `div.row ~ div.row` means?

Comment: It is [the general sisbling combinator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10782054/87015)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#menuModal" ).find( "div.row > div.col-xs-6 > span" ).slice(1).css( "color", "#669900" );
```