# Activate hover CSS of another class?

Tags: html, css

In this code the CSS will make the Image "grow" when you hover over it. However , I'd like to make the image grow when you hover over the word "github" (next to the image).

```
<style>
    .hvr-grow {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-property: transform;
      transition-property: transform;
    }
    .hvr-grow:hover, .hvr-grow:focus, .hvr-grow:active {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
</style>


<a href=""><img class ="hvr-grow" src="Images/github.png"> GitHub</a>
```

Comment: Would it work to apply your current styling to `a:hover .hvr-grow { ... }` and so on? Or is that not the result you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't access previous siblings with only css, so you can't make the image grow when you hover on `GitHub` after it, but you can put `GitHub` in a label and use `float:right` to make it appear in the right side of the image and use `label:hover + img` to make the image grow when you hover on the label :

```css
.hvr-grow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: transform;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

a label:hover+img,
.hvr-grow:focus,
.hvr-grow:active {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

a label {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <label>GitHub</label>
  <img class="hvr-grow" src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/790/PNG/512/github_icon-icons.com_65450.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the image is a child to the anchor element, you can use the child selector notation:

```
<style type="text/css">
a:hover .hvr-grow,
a:focus .hvr-grow,
a:active .hvr-grow {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer makes the image grow when you hover over both the image and the text... if you want it to grow ONLY when you hover over the text you can do something like this.

```css
.github:hover ~ .image {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <span class="github">Github</span>
  <img class="image" src="https://spin.atomicobject.com/wp-content/uploads/20171003153036/github-logo.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works best for my usecase. What does this tilda syntax mean in CSS?

Comment: You can think of it as a 'next to' selector. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean).