# The symbol of ~ in less file style of css preprocessor, what does it mean

Tags: css, less

`@card-prefix-cls: ~"@{css-prefix}card";`
I have seen the statement in less extension file of css style (not in css file), What does the symbol tilde(~) mean in less style file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "~" (tilde/squiggle/twiddle) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean)

Answer (score 3):

The symbol of tilde of ~ in less style file, it is a escaping symbol. Escaping allows you to use any arbitrary string as property or variable value. Anything inside `~"anything"` or `~'anything'` is used as is with no changes except interpolation.

```
@min768: ~"(min-width: 768px)";
.element {
  @media @min768 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}
```

results in

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .element {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}
```

The answer comes from less document. [document link](http://lesscss.org/#escaping)