# What is the problem with the sibling selector when it comes first?

Tags: html, css

I have this form and I can't select the sibling "label" to style it. However, when I put the "label" under the "input" it works. I want to style it as it is to be easy to control its style.
here is a link: https://jsfiddle.net/grucdymb/18/

```
<form action="">

  <div class="box">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" 
placeholder="example@email.com" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="email"> This is working </label>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <label for="subject"> This is not working </label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" 
autocomplete="off" required>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: *The general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches the second element **only if it follows the first element*** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Comment: This answer here expands on what Ben stated above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean

Comment: Why don't you style by using nth-of-type on the div?

So example:-
.box:nth-of-type(2) label {color:red;}

Comment: @Brad they want to style the label depending on the :focus state of the input.

Comment: Thank you all. I made it with jQuery, it is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not apply for the later example, because the `label` does not follow the `input` element.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator):

> The **general sibling combinator** (`~`) separates two selectors and matches
>   the second element only if it follows the first element (though not
>   necessarily immediately), and both are children of the same parent
>   element.

Of special note is this part in particular:

> ...**matches the second element only if it follows the first element**...