# Find class after a certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of elements with the same class `month`. Some of them might have the class `cal` as well, and only one element of the list has the class `today`.

I'd like to search for the first element with the class `cal`, but only after the element `today` is found

So for example, if I have the following list:

```
<ul id="eventCal">
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month cal">Not show because it's before TODAY</li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month today">Today</li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month cal">To show as it's the first CAL after the TODAY</li>
<li class="month cal">Not show because is not the first CAL</li>
<li class="month"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `:first` to get the first today li and then use `nextAll` with `:first` to get first cal after today

```js
$(function(){
  var text = $('#eventCal li.today:first').nextAll('li.cal:first').text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="eventCal">
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month cal">Not show because it's before TODAY</li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month today">Today</li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month cal">To show as it's the first CAL after the TODAY</li>
<li class="month cal">Not show because is not the first CAL</li>
<li class="month"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following selector:

```
document.querySelector('.today ~ .cal') or $('.today ~ .cal').first();
```

This will grab the first `.cal` class after the first `.today` class. For more information about the `~` selector, see [What does the “~” (tilde/squiggle/twiddle) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean)

```js
$('.today ~ .cal').first().css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="eventCal">
  <li class="month"></li>
  <li class="month cal">Not show because it's before TODAY</li>
  <li class="month"></li>
  <li class="month"></li>
  <li class="month"></li>
  <li class="month today">Today</li>
  <li class="month"></li>
  <li class="month cal">To show as it's the first CAL after the TODAY</li>
  <li class="month cal">Not show because is not the first CAL</li>
  <li class="month"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that with jQuery and you already have the `.today` element, you can use [`nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to find the all following siblings that match the selector and limit it to the first `.cal` using `:first`:

```js
let today = $('.today')
today.nextAll('.cal:first').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="eventCal">
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month cal">Not show because it's before TODAY</li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month today">Today</li>
<li class="month"></li>
<li class="month cal">To show as it's the first CAL after the TODAY</li>
<li class="month cal">Not show because is not the first CAL</li>
<li class="month"></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to have all following sibling that match the selector `.cal`, then you can remove the `:first`

If you don't have the `today` element and you are only interested in the the `cal` element, you can use `$('.today ~ .cal').first()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only the first `cal` after class `today` then use the following selector:

```
 $("#eventCal .month.cal").hide();
 $("#eventCal .today").nextAll(".month.cal:first").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using only `css` you can achieve it

By using `.today ~ .cal` you get all `.cal` after `.today`, but this will give you the full list `.cal` after `.today` so to exclude all `.cal` after the first appearance of `.cal` you can use this `:not(.cal) + .cal`

so the css selector will be `.today ~ :not(.cal) + .cal`

```css
.today ~ :not(.cal) + .cal
{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="eventCal">
<li class="month">No</li>
<li class="month cal">Not show because it's before TODAY</li>
<li class="month">No</li>
<li class="month">No</li>
<li class="month">No</li>
<li class="month today">Today</li>
<li class="month">No</li>
<li class="month cal">To show as it's the first CAL after the TODAY</li>
<li class="month cal">Not show because is not the first CAL</li>
<li class="month ">No</li>
</ul>
```