# Find class after a certain element even if they are not siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of elements with the same class `month`. Some of them might have the class `cal` as well, and only one element of the list has the class `today`.

I'd like to search for the first element with the class `cal`, but only after the element `today` is found. The tricky part here is that the elements might not be siblings. If they were siblings, this would work:

```
 $('#eventCal .today').nextAll('#eventCal .cal:first').text();
```

So for example, if I have the following list, how could I target the first `cal` after `today`?

```html
<div id="eventCal">
    <ul>
        <li class="month"></li>
        <li class="month cal">Not show because it's before TODAY</li>
        <li class="month"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="month"></li>
        <li class="month today">Today</li>
        <li class="month"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="month cal">To show as it's the first CAL after the TODAY</li>
        <li class="month cal">Not show because is not the first CAL</li>
        <li class="month"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `direct siblings` => what do you mean?

Comment: @Pedram Sorry I meant siblings, without the direct

Comment: Your code works if all the `li` are in only 1 `ul`

Comment: Plz elaborate `direct siblings` Your explanation is not clear enough

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find class after a certain element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610159/find-class-after-a-certain-element)

Comment: @Basil the link you have referred is also the question by the same OP as above

Comment: I know i have an answer there

Comment: @Basil no because they are all siblings. The point here is that the elements *are not* siblings.

Comment: @AmanjotKaur that's the thing. They are not siblings, so I need to find the way to target the CAL even though they are not siblings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work when the `li` are not all siblings you can get the index of the `.today` element within all `.month` elements. Then you can get all `.month` following that, and retrieve the first `.cal` using `filter()`, like this:

```js
var todayIndex = $('.month.today').index();
var $cal = $(`.month:gt(${todayIndex})`).filter('.cal:first').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="eventCal">
    <ul>
        <li class="month"></li>
        <li class="month cal">Not show because it's before TODAY</li>
        <li class="month"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="month"></li>
        <li class="month today">Today</li>
        <li class="month"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="month cal">To show as it's the first CAL after the TODAY</li>
        <li class="month cal">Not show because is not the first CAL</li>
        <li class="month"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is, find it by `parent` plus `nextAll` like below:

```js
$('.month').each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('today')) {
    $(this).parent().nextAll().find('.cal:first').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="eventCal">
  <ul>
    <li class="month"></li>
    <li class="month cal">Not show because it's before TODAY</li>
    <li class="month"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="month"></li>
    <li class="month today">Today</li>
    <li class="month"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="month cal">To show as it's the first CAL after the TODAY</li>
    <li class="month cal">Not show because is not the first CAL</li>
    <li class="month"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or you can easily get it like this:

```js
$('.today').parent().nextAll().find('.cal:first').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="eventCal">
  <ul>
    <li class="month"></li>
    <li class="month cal">Not show because it's before TODAY</li>
    <li class="month"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="month"></li>
    <li class="month today">Today</li>
    <li class="month"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="month cal">To show as it's the first CAL after the TODAY</li>
    <li class="month cal">Not show because is not the first CAL</li>
    <li class="month"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is redundant given the selector.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think second example much better

Comment: Note that your examples fail if there is another `ul` with a `.cal` in it: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/t2om9s05/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var foundToday = false;

  $('.month').each(function (idx,item) { 
         if( $(this).hasClass('cal') ){
            foundToday = true;
         }

         if(foundToday){
            if( $(this).hasClass('today') ){
                console.log($(this).text())
            }
         }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the next solution is quite simple.

```
var first_cal = ''
if($('.today').siblings('.cal').length){
    first_cal = $('.today').siblings('.cal').html()
}else{
    first_cal = $('.today').parent().nextAll('ul').find('.cal').html();
}

$('.result').text(first_cal);
```

What we do is to check if .today has siblings with cal, if not, we search the first cal starting from the next ul.

Notice that you can put as many ul without cal as you want after the ul that contains today, it wont affect the result.

**Here an example on fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/Samuel10F/utna63qx/