# I don't understand the ~ * css selectors combination

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to reconstruct the '[Toggling elements with a hidden checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)' code by myself, but I don't understand the selectors syntax:

```
#expand-toggle:checked ~ * .expandable {visibility: visible;}
```

Why we need both ~ and *?

Why using just the ~ selector is not enough?

Thank you

Comment: You will definitely find your answer in the documentation. Also check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean

Answer (score 1):

Let's review the HTML for that sample:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="expand-toggle" />

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Column #1</th><th>Column #2</th><th>Column #3</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="expandable"><td>[more text]</td><td>[more text]</td><td>[more text]</td></tr>
    <tr><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td></tr>
    <tr><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td></tr>
    <tr class="expandable"><td>[more text]</td><td>[more text]</td><td>[more text]</td></tr>
    <tr class="expandable"><td>[more text]</td><td>[more text]</td><td>[more text]</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<label for="expand-toggle" id="expand-btn">Toggle hidden rows</label>
```

Recall that the `~` combinator is a sibling combinator. If the selector were to read `#expand-toggle:checked ~ .expandable`, that would require the `.expandable` element to follow after the checkbox but not within some other element. In this case, `.expandable` is a `tr` within a `table`. That `table` is a sibling of the checkbox.

Perhaps swapping the `*` for a `table` would make the selector clearer:

```css
#expand-toggle:checked ~ table .expandable {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Either one could be used; I'm guessing the author went with `*` to save space — evidently, at the cost of readability.