# CSS selector for elements within a sibling

Tags: html, css

W/O JavaScript, I can control the display of tables by using CSS and check boxes as in this example, [Functional sibling selector example](http://julianlocals.com/cwhii/2021/qs/sib.html) using the sibling selector which is described in [What does the “~” (tilde/squiggle/twiddle) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean)

```css
#C-control:checked ~ .C-content {display: table;}
#F-control:checked ~ .F-content {display: table;}
.C-content                      {display: none;}
.F-content                      {display: none;}
```

```html
<input id='C-control' type='checkbox'>C
<input id='F-control' type='checkbox'>F

<table class='C-content'>
<tr><td>Bern</td><td>ZZZZ</td></tr>
<tr><td>Nairobi</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
</table>

<table class='F-content'>
<tr><td>Dallas</td><td>yyyy</td></tr>
<tr><td>New York</td><td>AAA</td></tr>
</table>
```

I would like to control the display of individual rows in a similar manner, [Non-functional by row example](http://julianlocals.com/cwhii/2021/qs/byrow.html)

[image: Non-functional by row code]

```css
#C-control:checked ~ .C-content {display: table-row;}
#F-control:checked ~ .F-content {display: table-row;}
.C-content                      {display: none;}
.F-content                      {display: none;}
```

```html
<input id='C-control' type='checkbox'>C
<input id='F-control' type='checkbox'>F

<table>
<tr class='C-content'><td>Bern</td><td>ZZZZ</td></tr>
<tr class='F-content'><td>Dallas</td><td>yyyy</td></tr>
<tr class='C-content'><td>Nairobi</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
<tr class='F-content'><td>New York</td><td>AAA</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Basically you have to first establish what sibling you mean then go deeper. Adding `table` into the selector after the `~` sibling selector will do that.

Your first example worked because the table had the classes and both of the tables were direct siblings of the checkboxes.

```css
#C-control:checked ~ table .C-content {display: table-row;}
/*       I added this --^  */
#F-control:checked ~ table .F-content {display: table-row;}
/*           and this --^  */
.C-content                      {display: none;}
.F-content                      {display: none;}
```

```html
<input id='C-control' type='checkbox'>C
<input id='F-control' type='checkbox'>F

<table>
  <tr class='C-content'><td>Bern</td><td>ZZZZ</td></tr>
  <tr class='F-content'><td>Dallas</td><td>yyyy</td></tr>
  <tr class='C-content'><td>Nairobi</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
  <tr class='F-content'><td>New York</td><td>AAA</td></tr>
</table>
```