# Jquery Selector : How to get the total number of div formErrorContent class

Tags: jquery

How to find the total number of **formErrorContent** for ID **cardZip** .

```
<div class="fieldCont">
   <label for="cardZip" class="errdLabel">Billing Zip Code</label>
   <input type="text" name="cardZip" id="cardZip" class="" maxlength="5">
   <div class="formErrorContent">Billing Zip Code Required field<br></div>
   <div class="formErrorContent">Billing Zip Code Required field<br></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#cardZip ~ .formErrorContent").length`

Comment: it works , what is ~ (telda)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean