# Why does checkbox not change the color style of the div element?

Tags: css, reactjs

***React (HTML)***

```
<div className={"OK"}>OK</div>
<input type="checkbox" id={"MainPage-checkbox-menu"} />
<label htmlFor={"MainPage-checkbox-menu"}></label>
```

***CSS***

```
#MainPage-checkbox-menu:checked ~ .OK {
  color: #8ef6ad;
}
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-chandrasekhar-wljfw?file=/src/App.js)

I seem to be doing everything right but the checkbox does not change the color style of the div element. How to make the checkbox change the color of the div element ?

Comment: Place your "ok" class element after  the "MainPage-checkbox-menu" . Its is because the order of selectors in css

Comment: @DaniyaNiazi you should add your comment as an answer so it can be accepted; 
 as you note, the ~ css operator requires that the left hand element precedes the right hand one.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean

Comment: is there any way to request the top item ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your CSS selectors, you need the element with the class `OK` to be placed below the `:checked` element. So your markup should look like this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="checkbox" id={"MainPage-checkbox-menu"} />
      <div className={"OK"}>OK</div>
      <label htmlFor={"MainPage-checkbox-menu"}></label>
    </div>
  );
}
```