# Why isn't :checked pseudo-element working for my hamburger menu in CSS and HTML?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I've been making a sticky navbar for my site and it has a hamburguer menu on the top right corner. I want to make so that, with only CSS and HTML, the hamburguer menu can hide and show itself using the `:checked` pseudo-element.

```css
@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  label #btn {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #34495e;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    /*hides navbar*/
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  /*when user clicks button, change the icon and bring the mobile <ul>*/
  #check:checked~ul {
    left: 0;
    /*not working (doesn't change value of left:)*/
  }
  #check:checked~label #btn {
    display: none;
  }
  #check:checked~label #cancel {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">ITEM 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ITEM 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ITEM 3</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<!--hamburguer menu-->
<label for="check">
  <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
```

When the page gets shrinked down, the `<ul>` goes hidden with `left: -100%;` and was supposed to come back with `#check:checked ~ ul{left: 0;}`. The problem is that this doesn't work, actually, nothing I write inside that pseudo-element for `<ul>` works (like changing the backgroung color for instance). However, `#check:checked ~ label #btn` and `#check:checked ~ label #cancel` work just fine.

If I type `left: 0` on the Firefox Developer Tools, the `<ul>` shows up! So I think the problem must be with the `#check:checked` pseudo-element.

Comment: `#check:checked ~ ul`  means select an `<ul>` that is preceded (not necessarily immediately) by a `:checked` element that has an `id` of `check`. Your `<ul>` precededs `<input id="check">`, so the selector fails to select anything. That being said, you can either use [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) or move your `#check` to before `ul`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "~" (tilde/squiggle/twiddle) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean)

Comment: You need to alter your HTML so that the ul comes after the input.

Comment: Yeah, I was using it the wrong way... and now I find out there is no way to select previous sibling or previous parent, That's another problem because I need ```#checkbox``` after ```<ul>```, but I'll try to find a way around that.